# Dialup modem transmission protocols and reates (client and server)

Tags: modem, dial-up, client-server, transmission, rates

Does anybody know why when connecting two dial-up modems the maximum protocol you can use to stablish the communication is V.34 -33.6K?

I've read that you can connect with the server modems of the ISP using V.92 or V.90 and I would like to know if there is any explanation to this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

V.92/V.90 requires one end of the link (in this case the ISP) to have digital access to the telephone network to work.

Your two modems will be connecting in analogue and so can only support V.34 at most.

Comment: You beat me to it. :-) +1. http://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-V.90-199809-I!!PDF-E&type=items

Answer (score -1):

If you have a bad connection line, e.g. noise in the line, so the established speed will drop down to values as the V.34. The connection speed is established at the handshake process (the beginning of transmission).

A comprehensive list of connections speeds can be found at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_device_bandwidths .

To achieve the maximum speed (56K over telephone line) you must have a very good quality line (no noise).

Comment: Not answering the question - and no, sorry, 56k is not reachable over a perfect connection with normal modems on both ends.